# concatenate quosures and string

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval

I'm looking for a way to concatenate a quosure and a string whose result is a quosure. Actually, if I use `paste0()` and `quo_name()`, I can do it. But I wonder if there is a more elegant alternative to write a function in my package. This is a generic example:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data_frame(
  z_1 = 1,
  z_2 = 2,
  y_1 = 10,
  y_2 = 20
)

get_var <- function(.data, var) {
  xx = enquo(var)

  select(.data, paste0(quo_name(xx), "_1"), paste0(quo_name(xx), "_2"))
}

get_var(df, z)
# A tibble: 1 x 2
    z_1   z_2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without a function, this is how you do it using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  select(starts_with("z_"))
```

You can also create a function and pass in a string for the variable name like this:

```
get_var= function(df, var){
  df %>%
    select(starts_with(paste0(var, "_")))
}

get_var(df, "z")
```

Now, the tricky part comes when you are trying to pass in the variable name without quoting it into a function (the R code, not the value it contains). One way of doing it would be `deparse` + `substitute` in Base R. This converts the *symbol* supplied to `var` to a string, which is convenient for later use within the function:

```
get_var = function(df, var){
  var_quo = deparse(substitute(var))
  df %>%
    select(starts_with(paste0(var_quo, "_")))
}
```

Finally, here is how to do the same with `enquo` and `quo_name` in `rlang/tidyverse` package:

```
library(rlang)
get_var = function(df, var){
  var_quo = quo_name(enquo(var))
  df %>%
    select(starts_with(paste0(var_quo, "_")))
}

get_var(df, z)
get_var(df, y)
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
    z_1   z_2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2

# A tibble: 1 × 2
    y_1   y_2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1    10    20
```

**Notes:**

1. quosures are quoted expressions that keep track of an environment.
2. `enquo` takes a symbol referring to a function's argument, quotes the R code and bundles it with the function's environment in a quosure.
3. `quo_name` formats a quosure into a string, which can be used later in the function.
4. `quo_text` is similar to `quo_name` but does not check for whether the input is a symbol.

Check these:

1. [`rlang` documentation](http://rlang.tidyverse.org/reference/quosure.html)
2. [Non-Standard Evaluation in R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html)
3. `?enquo`
4. `?quo_name`

Comment: If you can pass a variable name to your select, I'll upvote. `starts_with` is the approach I'd use

Comment: @CPark I see. So you want to be able to pass the variable itself and not a string like `"z"`? For instance, `get_var(df, "z")` would not be satisfactory?

Comment: I'm not the OP btw. Basically OP wants to define a function where the data frame and column-to-select are dynamically passed as arguments.

Comment: @CPak My bad. Does this look more like what OP might have wanted?